# Given an array of json objects, how do I convert values in each object to an int or float?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given an array of json objects, how do I convert values in each object to an int or float?

```
var data = [{
    "rank": "1",
    "name": "Bill"
  },
  {
    "rank": "2",
    "name": "Ted"
  },
  {
    "rank": "3",
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "rank": "4",
    "name": "Jane"
  }
]
```

The json objects I'm using are much larger, in both dimensions, so I am trying to figure out how I can use the **map** function to convert the "*rank*" part from a `string` to an `int`. There are other parts I want to convert to floats too, but right now sorting by "rank" sorts `1,10,11,12,etc`.

How can I do this? I'm using React/ES6/JSX/Babel, or whatever that amalgamation is.

Comment: Why is the data source storing the ranks as strings anyway, JSON supports numbers out of the box?

Comment: That is just how the source data is structured, I wish it wasn't that way.

Comment: Fair enough! We've all been there before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply map over your data array and return a new object with your user data while parsing the `"rank"` to a `Number`.

You can use `parseInt` and `parseFloat` where necessary.

```js
const data = [
    {"rank": "1","name": "Bill"},
    {"rank": "2","name": "Ted"},
    {"rank": "3","name": "John"},
    {"rank": "4","name": "Jane"}
]

const formatted = data.map(user => ({ 
  ...user, // collect all the properties of each user
  rank: parseInt(user.rank) // specifically parse the rank
}))

console.log('data', data)
console.log('formatted', formatted)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can use the map function**

```
 var data = [{"rank": "1","name": "Bill"},
            {"rank": "2.4","name": "Ted"},
            {"rank": "3","name": "John"},
            {"rank": "4.5","name": "Jane"}];

 data.map(d => d.rank = +d.rank);    

 console.log(data);
```

**Check this** [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/ab67dojr/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use + operator to convert to int or float. Try this:

```js
var data = [
    {"rank": "1","name": "Bill"},
    {"rank": "2.4","name": "Ted"},
    {"rank": "3","name": "John"},
    {"rank": "4.5","name": "Jane"}];
    
data.forEach(d => d.rank = +d.rank);    

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert from `string` to `number`.

```js
var data = [{
        "rank": "1",
        "name": "Bill"
    },
    {
        "rank": "2",
        "name": "Ted"
    },
    {
        "rank": "3",
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "rank": "4",
        "name": "Jane"
    }
];

var newData = data.map(function (item) {
    item.rank = Number(item.rank)
    return item;
});

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+` to convert string to number.

```js
var data = [ {"rank": "1","name": "Bill"}, {"rank": "2","name": "Ted"}, {"rank": "3","name": "John"}, {"rank": "4","name": "Jane"}],
    result = data.map(({rank, name}) => ({rank : +rank, name}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```